# Lightning Component in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I have created Lightning Component in VF Page in which I have used the lightning component from the managed package.
In my lightning app I have already defined `<aura:dependency resource="managed package component"/>`

This is perfectly working for the internal users, but when I tried to access it through the community(External User) the lightning Spinner kips loading to infinite time.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you check your Developer Console in the browser for any errors? Any other troubleshooting you've tried?

Comment: [Share Lightning Out Apps with Non-Authenticated Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_public_apps.htm)

Comment: I have tried to troubleshoot but I am not getting any errors. And I have already implemented access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess"